# In Protractor, is it possible to run an Angular modules function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I'm very new to Javascript and Protractor. Still trying to get my head around simple syntax so forgive me if I'm way off base here.

So our angular app, has a module with a factory that generates toast messages. I'd like to disable all toast messages during my E2E testing. We have a function within the factory to disable toasts. Here's some simplified code.

```
//the module
var module = angular.module('toast',[]);

//the factory
module.factory('tf',[function tf(){

//factory code

//the function within the module's factory
moduleFactory.enable = function(enable){
        isEnabled = enable;
    };
}]);
```

My question is, can I access that function in protractor to turn that to false?

I've been searching around and it seems that mocking is how to do it. Something similar to how you disable angular animations.

```
// Disable animations so e2e tests run more quickly
var disableNgAnimate = function() {
angular.module('disableNgAnimate', []).run(['$animate', function($animate) {
$animate.enabled(false);
 }]);
};

browser.addMockModule('disableNgAnimate', disableNgAnimate);
```

However, I'm struggling with the syntax on accessing the factory's function within the module...Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I've found the solution for anyone else that may have a similar issue.

Using the executeScript function of protractor.

```
browser.executeScript(function() 
{
    return angular.element(document).injector().get('toastFactory').enableToasts(false);
});
```